# BeautifulSoup, get text of all td's (some text with commas) inside tr's

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

Im currently working on a table that is created in ASP, its very messy but with some code help I think Ill be getting what I need from this table.
I have an HTML code that I want the output to be one array for each tr with td's. I also do not want the "-" to be a part of the output in the arrays.

Some td's have 2 commas and some texts in the td's are separated by only an empty space " ":

The code is like this

```
  <tr bgcolor="#EFEFEF">
  <td>
   <a href="free.asp?detail=hide&amp;c_id=4342141">
    <img align="absmiddle" border="0" hspace="0" src="pic/bullet.gif" vspace="0"/>
   </a>
  </td>
  <td>
   4342141
  </td>
  <td width="10">
  </td>
  <td>
   25.07.2018 09:00
  </td>
  <td width="10">
  </td>
  <td>
   Golbasi Ankara, Turkey
  </td>
  <td width="10">
   -
  </td>
  <td>
   Konya Havalimani Turkey
  </td>
  <td colspan="2">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#EFEFEF" height="3">
  <td colspan="10">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="1">
  <td colspan="10">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#DDDDDD" height="6">
  <td colspan="10">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="1">
  <td colspan="10">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#DEE3E7" height="3">
  <td colspan="10">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#DEE3E7">
  <td>
   <a href="free.asp?detail=hide&amp;c_id=4134123">
    <img align="absmiddle" border="0" hspace="0" src="pic/bullet.gif" vspace="0"/>
   </a>
  </td>
  <td>
   4134123
  </td>
  <td width="10">
  </td>
  <td>
   26.07.2018 09:00
  </td>
  <td width="10">
  </td>
  <td>
   Kucuktepe, Van, Turkey
  </td>
  <td width="10">
   -
  </td>
  <td>
   Maltepe, Istanbul, Turkey
  </td>
  <td colspan="2">
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Some td's have 2 commas and some texts in the td's are separated by only an empty space " ":

```
[['4342141', '25.07.2018', '09:00', 'Golbasi Ankara, Turkey', '-', 'Konya Havalimani Turkey', 'free.asp?detail=hide&c_id=4342141'], ['4134123', '26.07.2018', '09:00', 'Kucuktepe, Van, Turkey', '-', 'Maltepe, Istanbul, Turkey', 'free.asp?detail=hide&c_id=4134123']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `data` will hold the HTML text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
rows = []
for tr in soup.select('tr'):
    row = [td.text.strip() for td in tr.select('td') if td.text.strip() and td.text.strip() != '-']
    if row:
        rows.append(row)

pprint(rows, width=120)
```

This will print:

```
[['4342141', '25.07.2018 09:00', 'Golbasi Ankara, Turkey', 'Konya Havalimani Turkey'],
 ['4134123', '26.07.2018 09:00', 'Kucuktepe, Van, Turkey', 'Maltepe, Istanbul, Turkey']]
```

For writing the `rows` list to csv you can use this script:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Then in `data.csv` file you will have:

```
4342141,25.07.2018 09:00,"Golbasi Ankara, Turkey",Konya Havalimani Turkey
4134123,26.07.2018 09:00,"Kucuktepe, Van, Turkey","Maltepe, Istanbul, Turkey"
```

Comment: Whats the "pprint" youre using here?

Comment: @YasirAkdeniz `pprint` stands for pretty-print - https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html. It's just there for having the output more prettier. You can freely substitute it for `print()` - without the `width` parameter of course.

Comment: would it be in handy when exporting to csv? ultimately I want to create a csv with 4 columns: "id", "date", "from", "to". but im afraid those commas will create trouble for me on Excel when doing "text to column" with delimited by commas....

Comment: @YasirAkdeniz No, `pprint` doesn't solve exporting to csv. For that use `csv` module - https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: would it be in handy when exporting to csv? ultimately I want to create a csv with 4 columns: "id", "date", "from", "to". but im afraid those commas will create trouble for me on Excel when doing "text to column" with delimited by commas....

Comment: could I somehow just remove the commas in the td's, just to make it easier on Excel???

Comment: @YasirAkdeniz see my updated answer how to write to csv file

Comment: thank you so much man, Ive been struggling with this for 2 days :S.

Comment: you also know how I can remove the commas in the td's so the output would be like[4134123, 26.07.2018 09:00, Kucuktepe Van Turkey, Maltepe Istanbul Turkey] ?

Comment: @YasirAkdeniz you use `replace()` method: `row = [td.text.strip().replace(',', '') for td in tr.select('td') if td.text.strip() and td.text.strip() != '-']`